# Showing Empty after using eloquent un laravel

Tags: php, laravel, orm, eloquent

I have `MyRoom.php` and `TotalCity.php` in my project in which each room is categorizes inside a city

so that I did this in MyRoom.php

```
public function location()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(TotalCity::class, 'location_id')->withTrashed();
}
```

and I did this in TotalCity.php

```
public function location()
{
    return $this->hasMany(MyRoom::class , 'total_city_id')->withTrashed();
}
```

I have passed id with routes and controller like this 
home.blade.php
    id)}}">{{ $row->name }}

web.php

```
Route::get('/city/{id}/rooms/','SiteController@room')->name('room');
```

SiteController.php

```
public function room($id) {
    $room = TotalCity::find($id)->location;
    return view('frontend.pages.rooms', compact('room'));
}
```

rooms.blade.php

```
@foreach($room as $row)
        <div class="room">
            <a href="{{ route('description',$row->id) }}"><img src="{{ asset(env('UPLOAD_PATH').'/' . $row['photoi1']) }}"/></a>
        </div>
        @endforeach
```

But this is not showing any rooms in any city while i have stored cities and rooms which comes under particular city in my database.

Answer (score 0):

In the relationship method, you should mention foreign key and owner key as well,
for example in MyRoom.php:

```php
public function location()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(TotalCity::class, 'location_id', 'total_city_primary_key')->withTrashed();
}
```

you can read [laravel documentioation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many-inverse) for more detail.

Comment: still the same
Can I have u with teamviewer for couple of minutes please ?

Comment: Actually you don't need to mention the foreign key nor the local key.

Answer (score 0):

foreignKey in TotalCity model is wrong :

```
public function location(){
    return $this->hasMany(MyRoom::class, 'location_id')->withTrashed();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I strongly recommend you to change your model's names to **City** and **Room**. If you dont want to, make sure in both models you're connecting them to the correct table, you can achieve that using the `$table` variable in both models, like this:

```
$table = 'your_table_name';
```

This will make sure the table is connected right.

Also, you should make a few changes:

In your **TotalCity** model do this:

```
public function rooms()
{
    return $this->hasMany(MyRoom::class , 'total_city_id')->withTrashed();
}
```

In your **MyRoom** model do this:

```
public function city()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(TotalCity::class)->withTrashed();
}
```

In your **SiteController** do this:

```
public function room($id) {
    $rooms = TotalCity::find($id)->rooms;
    return view('frontend.pages.rooms', compact('rooms'));
}
```

In your **View**

```
@foreach($rooms as $room)
        <h2>{{$room->name}}</h2>
        <div class="room">
            <a href="{{ route('description',$room->id) }}"><img src="{{ asset(env('UPLOAD_PATH').'/' . $room['photoi1']) }}"/></a>
        </div>
@endforeach
```

Comment: Im glad i could help, friend. Please accept this answer (check button) :)